# React-native get cookies from WebView

Tags: react-native, cookies, webview

I have a webview, and I am logging into a website in it, and I want the auth cookies to persist the login, so I can just set the cookie for the user every time, so they don't need to log in every time.

Is this possible?
How can I get the cookie from the webview?

Here is my webview:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: "anywebsite.com" }}
      onLoadStart={this.loadingStarted}
      onLoad={this.loadingEnded}
    />
  </View>
```

Comment: use CookieManager for manage WebViews' cookie issue: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/webkit/CookieManager

Comment: Hey thanks, but I would need it to work on IOS too, hence the react-native project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-cookies](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies) for handling cookies in RN.

Note that there is also an attribute on WebView called [thirdPartyCookiesEnabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#thirdpartycookiesenabled). You should try it out and see if it works for your case, cause manually setting and getting the cookies in the WebView takes some time to set up even with a library like react-native-cookies.